# how to make scrollable ListView but not to fill whole screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I want to make screen with TextView on top (title)
a ListView in the middle
and buttons on the bottom.
How to place ListView that will fill entire space between top TextView and bottom Buttons and be able to scroll its content ?

Now, when my list grows, it pushes bottom button outside the screen.

I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvLocations"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
    <TextView android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
    />
    <Button android:text="LayerDrawable"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/layer_drawable"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The last `TextView` is used to make a gap and move `Button` to a bottom.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout`. Set the `layout_weight="1"` to your `ListView` with `layout_height="fill_parent"`. Remove weight of other elements.

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lvLocations"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
></ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:text="arg0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </LinearLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Previous" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Next" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is exactly how I have mine set up, and it works great.

Comment: You should avoid nested Layouts.

Comment: I try to avoid deeply nested layouts. I don't think that nesting down one level is bad.

Comment: Most of the time you'll be able to use a `RelativeLayout` where you use a nested one.

Comment: I know, I was having stupid issues with it and just stuck to what I understood better. `RelativeLayout`s are definitely handy, I just wasn't used to them when I wrote this.

Comment: I guess nesting layouts is fully acceptable. that's why there is a full View, ViewGroup etc. hierarchy.

Thanks for code :)  I have to learn more about layout_weight="1"

Comment: That says that it takes up as much space as all the other widgets with weight = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all your elements in a [layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html#Layout): [LinearLeyout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout) or [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#relativelayout).

Answer (score 0):

You can use help of android:layout_below="" and android:layout_above="" to achieve the desired result.
Hope this helps.